# jaxb validation event locator - row and col number of validation error

Tags: validation, jaxb

When doing JAXB marshalling I am collecting validation error and also want to get the line number and column number where the error occurs. I keep getting columnNumber=-1 and lineNumber=-1 for all the errors. Is there anything that I am forgetting?

Code sample:

```
Marshaller marshaler = jaxbCtx.createMarshaller();
marshaler.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
ValidationErrorCollector errorCollector = new ValidationErrorCollector();
marshaler.setEventHandler(errorCollector);
marshaler.setSchema(getSchema());
marshaler.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new MyNamespacePrefixMapper());
JAXBElement<RootObject> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<RootObject>(ROOT_QNAME, RootObject.class, (RootObject) rootObject);
marshaler.marshal(jaxbElement, new StringWriter());

for (ValidationEvent validationEvent : errorCollector.getValidationEvents()) {
validationEvent.getLocator().getColumnNumber(); // returns -1
validationEvent.getLocator().getLineNumber(); // returns -1
...

public class ValidationErrorCollector implements ValidationEventHandler {

    /** List of validation events (with validation errors). */
    private List<ValidationEvent> validationEvents = new ArrayList<ValidationEvent>();

    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent validationEvent) {
        // record the validation error
        validationEvents.add(validationEvent);
        // let validation continue
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which column and line number (in which file) do you expect to retrieve?
I think this is by design. Line number and column number are for ValidationEvent which happen on unmarshalling. In such a case you get the position of the problem in the XML file to be unmarshalled.

But in your case you are trying to marshall an object - hence there is no XML file and therefore you don't get a column or a line number.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes sense to me now that line number can be retrieved on umarhsalling only.

Answer (score 2):

That is the expected behavior.  When you're marshaling the source of the error comes from the object being marshalled.  The object can also be found through the event.

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that when I do marshalling I cannot get the line and column number since the marshalling is done from the objects and XML is not completed yet (which makes sense to me now), right? And only line number can be retrieved when I do umarshaling from XML into objects.

Comment: It's not really because the XML is not completed yet.  Instead the validation event is reporting where the problem occurred, and during a marshal operation the invalid data comes from the object.